# Pandas, how to slice list made columns

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine, i have a column made by a bunch of of lists.

```
Column A 
List A of userids
List B of userids
List C of userids
List D of userids
```

And i want to acess list A, through index. Normally, i would just do

```
df['Column A'][0]
```

End result should be:

```
['ELEMENT OF LIST A', 'ELEMENT OF LIST A']
```

But i get a weird keyerror : 0. Any ideas on what i could do so i get that specific end result? I want to know that because i need to acess a list value according to the index of my loop.

As asked here is the dict output of a single row. It was the best i could do considering the size of the suceding ones.

```
{'Steps': {0: '1-Onboarding + Retorno'},
 'CampaignSource': {0: 'abd-ecomm-sms'},
 'UserId': {0: ['07cf01d5-5179-4fa2-b3a1-a341cfa11625@tunnel.msging.net',
   '11f214d8-45dc-46d6-a9ae-8ae08a42cd7c@tunnel.msging.net',
   '2d24e127-a956-4946-af1f-47341761074b@tunnel.msging.net']}}
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's going on without a more structured sample of your dataframe. Will you please provide the output of `print(df.head(5).to_dict())`?

Comment: But of course, the things i the output has a huge size, because of the list and it is inside elements. So i am gonna try, to conglomerate everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column A': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']]}, index=['i', 'j'])

#     Column A
# i  [a, b, c]
# j     [d, e]
```

Doing `df['Column A'][0]` would try to access the index `0` of the Series, which doesn't exist and raises a `KeyError`.

If you want to get all first items of the lists (as a Series) use:

```
df['Column A'].str[0]
```

output:

```
i    a
j    d
Name: Column A, dtype: object
```

To get the first element of the list at indices `i`/`Column A`:

```
df.loc['i', 'Column A'][0]
# 'a'
```

and for the first element of the first list of `Column A`:

```
df['Column A'].iloc[0][0]
# 'a'
```